# Error ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.happydroids.droidtowers.entities.GridObject;

Tags: java, android, eclipse, casting, intellij-idea

I'm trying to compile the following project: https://github.com/pplante/droidtowers
(the December 02 version, which is the last one that works). I managed to get all the dependencies etc and it compiles both under eclipse and IntelliJ-IDEA (which is the original project). However, when running under eclipse the following error appears at this line:

```
Array<GridObject> rooms = new Array<GridObject>(gameGrid.getInstancesOf(Room.class).items);
```

This crashes the game after a new game is started, past the Main Menu.

Now, I know that the Room class extends GridObject, and this runs fine under IntelliJ. I can't wrap my head around what can be the problem, or difference between both executables, so any help would be welcome. Maybe there's a default in the compiler overriden in the IDEA project? (I made the eclipse project from scratch).

This is using the latest Java, and android sdk.

ADDENDUM: Here's the full stacktrace:

```
ago 05, 2013 3:14:57 PM com.happydroids.platform.DesktopUncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtException
SEVERE: Uncaught exception!
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.happydroids.droidtowers.entities.GridObject;
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:111)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.happydroids.droidtowers.entities.GridObject;
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.controllers.AvatarLayer.setupInitialAvatars(AvatarLayer.java:191)
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.scenes.TowerScene.create(TowerScene.java:145)
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.scenes.components.SceneManager.pushScene(SceneManager.java:39)
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.scenes.components.SceneManager.changeScene(SceneManager.java:26)
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.scenes.LoadTowerSplashScene.render(LoadTowerSplashScene.java:29)
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.DroidTowersGame.render(DroidTowersGame.java:216)
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.LwjglApplicationShim.render(LwjglApplicationShim.java:50)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:190)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:108)

com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.happydroids.droidtowers.entities.GridObject;
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:111)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.happydroids.droidtowers.entities.GridObject;
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.controllers.AvatarLayer.setupInitialAvatars(AvatarLayer.java:191)
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.scenes.TowerScene.create(TowerScene.java:145)
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.scenes.components.SceneManager.pushScene(SceneManager.java:39)
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.scenes.components.SceneManager.changeScene(SceneManager.java:26)
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.scenes.LoadTowerSplashScene.render(LoadTowerSplashScene.java:29)
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.DroidTowersGame.render(DroidTowersGame.java:216)
  at com.happydroids.droidtowers.LwjglApplicationShim.render(LwjglApplicationShim.java:50)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:190)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:108)
```

Comment: If you post the stacktrace, that would be great.

Comment: I added the stacktrace (don't know if I was supposed to add a comment mentioning it).
Anyway, I'm at a loss here... if I set Array<Object> x = ... it works fine. Also, .items returns an object of the type GridObject[] (so, a regular array), and the constructor for Array<GridObject> expects that type of object. Why am I getting a casting exception? Also, the array at this point contains 16 nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, can't say I "fixed" the error (apparently that's just the way generics work or something) but I removed ".items" and it worked, because it was redundant: it was basically taking a function that returns Array<GridObject>, it was converting it to an array GridObject[], then using a constructor to convert it back to a type Array<GridObject>.

The biggest mistery now is why IDEA didn't return an error at all. Could be some obscure compiler setting.